# How to cache a query in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord

I have the following query in my application

```
@categories = Category.joins(:posts).select('distinct categories.*').order('label')
```

This query gets loaded on every page view since the categories are displayed on every page. This seems messy to me since the list of categories are not getting updated that often. Is there a nifty way to cache just the query? I have tried

```
   Category.cache do
      @categories = Category.joins(:posts).select('distinct categories.*').order('label')
    end
```

but I still see the query getting loaded every time from the database in the development log.

Comment: Caching is turned off by default in development mode. Look in `config/environments/development.rb` to turn it on.

Comment: @Douglas F Shearer That setting controls whether Ruby classes are cached or reloaded with every request, not whether Active Record's query cache is enabled.

Answer (score 20):

In your controller, you can try something like:

```
@categories = Rails.cache.fetch('categories', :expires_in => 24.hours) { Category.joins(:posts).select('distinct categories.*').order('label') }
```

Which will only read to see if the following data block 'categories' has been cached and not expired. If expired after 24 hours, will then query the model and write the new record into Rails cache.

For more information, I followed the following [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

Try it out. I have it working this way. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use fragment caching for the part of your view template that displays the categories. This means that the categories will be served from the cache store and the query will only be executed once until the cache is expired (by using the `expire_fragment` method).

- [Fragment Caching Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching)

Comment: Since fragment caching makes use of Russian doll caching, it is easier to present a consistent view of the data than the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5712011/61048, which can either get out of date with the underlying data within the 24 hours, or must be explicitly invalidated.