# Loading variable from time to time in the controller with Whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I'm working on a project where i want to do a mysql query from time to time. The query is too long, and actually it's done when the user does a request.

I'm afraid if many users does the request, the application will be too slow to respond. So, I want to do the query and load it with the query response from time to time, and then, on a request, the action from the controller will use this variable, instead of doing the query again and again.

How can I do that using Whenever?

on the schedule.rb

```
every 5.minutes do
    runner "variable = Model.method"
end
```

and on the controller

```
def some_action
"the variable should be loaded here"

end
```

Comment: This is the completely wrong way to go about it. Use caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709773/how-to-cache-a-query-in-ruby-on-rails-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Damien Roche, you need to cache the results of the query. But, I don't think the example he gives is the best answer for you because you don't want for a user to wait for the query when it isn't cached, at the times when the cache is expired, even if this is a rare occurrence.
So you need to combine the periodic query with whenever, like you suggested, with a caching mechanism to store your query result, and retrieve it from the cache in your controller. since the runner is a different process, you will have to use a cache that is available to both the runner and your app. I recommend you look into Redis. it should be very simple to get it to work so that the runner runs the query and when it finishes writes a result set to the Redis cahce. The controller will then read the result set from the cache.

Comment: I combined both, used Whenever schedules to call a method from time to time, and caching it, then on the controller, i'm getting the value with Rails.cache.read(). That made the application run much faster.